# evaluation of fourier transform of electric potential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I would like to ask how to evaluate equation 7? I have spent hours and still have no idea how to get a(k).

[image]

Comment: it would be easier to help u if we would know what u have already tried.
But in principle this is a relativly straightforward contour integration exercise. 
Btw: Since when a dipole consists of two linecharges? thats an interesting definition...;)

Comment: I haven't learnt contour integral and am now reading books on it. Would be nice if someone can show me the steps for at least one part of it (like the real part) and so I can try to do the imaginary part myself.

Comment: the only trick is that the contour of integration changes depending on the sign of the parameter $k$. For $k>0$ take a semi-circle in the lower halfplane. For $k<0$ take a semi-circle in the upper half plane.

Comment: would be really nice if someone can demonstrates at least one part of it. Not even sure if I am evaluating the pole using the correct method

Comment: I manage to get the imaginary part, but not the real part. Can't figure out where the sgn(x) pops out.